# Scaling a variable that is an interaction of two variables, for GLM

Tags: scale, glm

Is there a way to scale all your variables *including your interaction variables, in a GLM?  For example, running the model works when I scale all single variables, but not the interactions.

This works:

```
mod_lm_scale <-glm( pa ~  
        scale(WC05) + scale(WC06) + scale(WC08) + 
        scale(WC13) + scale(WC15), 


data=sdmdata, 

family='binomial')
```

Trying to add a scaled interaction does not work.  See the last term: scale(WC05:WC06)

```
mod_lm_scale <-glm( pa ~  
        scale(WC05) + scale(WC06) + scale(WC08) + 
        scale(WC13) + scale(WC15), 
        scale(WC05:WC06),



data=sdmdata, 


family='binomial')
```

I receive this error when including the scaled interaction, and receive no errors when I don't include it:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = pa ~ scale(WC05_clipped) + scale(WC06_clipped) +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In WC05_clipped:WC06_clipped :
  numerical expression has 2869 elements: only the first used
2: In WC05_clipped:WC06_clipped :
  numerical expression has 2869 elements: only the first used
```